# Can't see Access Queries in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I am not able to import my data from Access into Excel because I can not find the query in the list.

```
SELECT "Assembly" AS Type, [Assembly Data].[Assembly Date] AS Dates, 
           [Serial Numbers].[Assembly Serial Numbers Check] AS [Serial Number], 
           [Assembly Data].[Work Order #] AS [Work Order #], 
           [Assembly Data].[Part #] AS [Part #], 
           [Assembly Data].[Assembly Line] AS Line, 
           [Assembly Data].[Assembly Shift] AS Shift, 
           [Assembly Data].[Assembly Notes] AS Notes, "" AS [Test Stand], 
           "" AS [Pass/Fail], "" AS [Type of Downtime], "" AS [Time Lost]
FROM [Assembly Data] 
INNER JOIN [Serial Numbers] 
        ON [Assembly Data].[ID Assembly] = [Serial Numbers].[ID Assembly Data]
WHERE ((([Assembly Data].[Assembly Date]) 
BETWEEN [Forms]![Main Screen Performance]![Modified Start Date] AND
        [Forms]![Main Screen Performance]![Modified End Date]));
```

Please let me know what I need to fix in this SQL so that I can see/link my database. Also I am a new to SQL, so it may not look great. Thank you in advance if you are able to help!

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access try converting your select query above to a "make table"query. Run this query in Access which will create a table, give the table a name in MS Access and then import the created table directly into Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Since your query relies on parameter values at runtime from Access form controls `[Forms]![Main Screen Performance]![Modified Start Date]` and `[Forms]![Main Screen Performance]![Modified End Date]`, its resultset cannot be imported into Excel and likely was excluded in the *Select Table* dialog to import Access tables or queries.

To resolve, consider creating a new, very similar query with named parameters not restricted to Access form controls. Then using application code like VBA, assign values to parameters for recordset build that will be copied to Excel spreadsheet:

**SQL** *(using table aliases and NULL)*

```sql
PARAMETERS start_date_param Datetime, end_date_param Datetime;
SELECT 'Assembly'AS Type, a.[Assembly Date] AS Dates, 
       [Serial Numbers].[Assembly Serial Numbers Check] AS [Serial Number], 
       a.[Work Order #] AS [Work Order #], 
       a.[Part #] AS [Part #], 
       a.[Assembly Line] AS Line, 
       a.[Assembly Shift] AS Shift, 
       a.[Assembly Notes] AS Notes, NULL AS [Test Stand], 
       NULL AS [Pass/Fail], NULL AS [Type of Downtime], NULL AS [Time Lost]
FROM [Assembly Data]  a
INNER JOIN [Serial Numbers] s
        ON a.[ID Assembly] = s.[ID Assembly Data]
WHERE (((a.[Assembly Date]) 
BETWEEN start_date_param AND end_date_param;
```

**VBA** *(using late-binding)*

```vb
Sub ParamQueryImport()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim conn As Object, db As Object, qdef As Object, rs As Object
    Dim i As Integer

    Set conn = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")

    Set db = conn.OpenDatabase("C:Path\To\Database.accdb")
    Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")

    qdef!start_date_param = "#01/01/2018#"
    qdef!end_date_param = "#08/13/2018#"

    Set rs = qdef.OpenRecordset()

    With Worksheets("MY SHEET NAME")
        ' COLUMN HEADERS
        For i = 1 To rs.Fields.Count
            .Cells(1, i) = rs.Fields(i - 1).Name
        Next i
        ' DATA ROWS
        .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With

    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    Msgbox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritial, "RUNTIME ERROR"
    Set rs = Nothing: Set qdef = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing
    Resume ExitHandle

ExitHandle:    
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```